# Custom Export to CSV button inside Tab-element

Tags: react-admin

Working with react-admin version 2.9.6. And I want to implement a export to CSV button inside a Tab element. The export should not be all the items for a specific resource but rather a sub field on a specific resource id.

I want to export the "export_data" for a specific post in the example below.

Example resource /posts/1

```
{
 id: 1,
 title: "some title"
 ....
 export_data: {
   some_data: "ddddd",
   ...
 }
}
```

The Show-view looks something like this:

```
export const PostsShow = (props) => (
    <Show {...props}>
        <TabbedShowLayout>
            <Tab label="General">
                ...
            </Tab>
            <Tab label="Other">
                ...
                <ExportButton ... />
            </Tab>
        </TabbedShowLayout>
    </Show>
);
```